# Selecionar campo da próxima linha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou precisando fazer uma consulta trazendo o segundo valor de um campo para a primeira linha, Ou seja, preciso que o valor do primeiro campo da coluna "Tempo1" seja preenchido com o valor do segundo campo da coluna "Tempo"..
Criei um campo vazio que é o campo "Tempo1" para fazer um case puxando os valores mas não estou conseguindo fazer o puxar o valor como eu quero.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

*Query:*

```
SELECT linhas,
       ctns,
       usuario,
       hora,
       dia,
       tempo,
       CASE
           WHEN tempo1 IS NULL THEN tempo
           ELSE tempo
       END AS tempo1
FROM
  (SELECT rownum AS linhas,
          a.ctn AS ctns,
          a.usu AS usuario,
          a.hh AS hora,
          a.dia1 AS dia,
          a.dia2 AS tempo,
          ' ' AS tempo1
   FROM
     (SELECT Distinct(DLYTRN.To_subnum) AS ctn,
                                           DLYTRN.usr_id AS usu,
                                                            To_Char (DLYTRN.trndte, 'HH24') AS HH,
                                                                                               To_Char (DLYTRN.trndte, 'DD') AS dia1,
                                                                                                                                To_Char (DLYTRN.ins_dt, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS dia2
      FROM DLYTRN
      WHERE DLYTRN.trndte >= trunc (sysdate,'MM') -60
        AND DLYTRN.oprcod = 'UPK'
        AND DLYTRN.actcod IN ('CASPCK',
                              'PLAPCK',
                              'OTRPCK')
        AND DLYTRN.usr_id = 'SCRUZ'
      ORDER BY To_Char (DLYTRN.ins_dt, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
               DLYTRN.usr_id) a)
```

Comment: Se precisarem de mais dados posso passar .... 
Tentei anexar um print que ajudaria muito no entendimento mas no consegui.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125%28v=sql.110%29.aspx     https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Bom Dia .... LEAD E LAG não dão resultado. tentei usá-los antes mesmos de postar a pergunta.

Comment: Tentou usar o lead e lag com a parte interna de sua sql <de SELECT rownum AS lin ... id) a)> ?

Comment: Tentei .... mas ele não aceita o comando ... :(

Comment: algo como USE xxxxxxx
GO
SELECT .... 
    LEAD(tempo, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY rownum,ctns,usuario,hora,dia1) AS Nexttempo
FROM (<sau sql>);

Comment: cara deu certo !!!!!!!

Comment: muito obrigado ....... obrigado mesmo .......

Comment: show de boolaaa \o/

Comment: Motta, desculpe abusar de sua inteligencia kkkk Mas deixa eu te perguntar mais uma coisa... Tem como colocar um filtro junto com o LEAD para ele subir o valor para linha de cima apenas se o usuario for o mesmo e caso nao seja o mesmo usuario ele colocario um "zero" ou deixaria o campo nulo ?

Answer (score 1):

LEAD E LAG

Vide 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125%28v=sql.110%29.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Usando a query como uma tabela virtual.

Comment: Faz um exemplo na sua resposta para agregar valor a ela.

Comment: Motta, desculpe abusar de sua inteligencia kkkk 

Mas deixa eu te perguntar mais uma coisa... 
Tem como colocar um filtro junto com o LEAD para ele subir o valor para linha de cima apenas se o usuario for o mesmo e caso nao seja o mesmo usuario ele colocario um "zero" ou deixaria o campo nulo ?

Comment: tente com o  PARTITION BY